# How to use any_value in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am looking to derive the columns 2 and 3 from 1 and 4 using sql, need advise

[image]

**output logics for `col_2` and `col_3`**

1. any of the values in col_1 group by col_4 is True , then col_2 is true col_3 is false
2. all the values in col_1 group by col_4 is false, then col_2 is false and col_3 is true
3. all the values in col_1 group by col_4 is true , then col_2 is false and col_3 is false

Comment: Is this input or output?

Comment: col_1 and col_4 input, col_2 and col_3 output

Comment: what's the logic behind *col_2* and *col_3* ?  I don't think `any_value()` is able to make the output you want.

Comment: Any other functions we could use to get the above output 
1 . any of the values in col_1 group by col_4 is True , then col_2 is true col_3 is false
2. all the values in col_1 group by col_4 is false, then col_2 is false and col_3 is true
3. all the values in col_1 group by col_4 is true , then col_2 is false and col_3 is false

Answer (score 2):

You seems to want [logical_or()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBblYm.png) and [logical_and()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBblYm.png) functions in BigQuery.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT col_4, col_1
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('aaaaabbbccc', '')) col_4 WITH offset
    JOIN UNNEST([false, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, true, true, true]) col_1 WITH offset
   USING (offset)
)
SELECT *,
       CASE
         WHEN LOGICAL_AND(col_1) OVER (PARTITION BY col_4) IS TRUE THEN STRUCT(false AS col2, false AS col_3)
         WHEN LOGICAL_OR(col_1) OVER (PARTITION BY col_4) IS FALSE THEN (false, true)
         ELSE (true, false)
       END.*
  FROM sample_table;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to count true and false values for each col_4 key inside a CTE or a subquery (whichever way works for you).
Then perform a join with the original table.
That way, you can then derive col_2 and col_3 directly by checking the counts of True and False in the final select statement.